# Cannot send e-mail notifications on jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins version  1.598 and email -ext plugin version 2.25
I want to send email notification when build is successful. When i make a build, the build is successful, and i can see following error on the console output:

```
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending email to: jangra.vatan94@gmail.com
ERROR: Could not send email as a part of the post-build publishers.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:localhost, port: 25, response: 421
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1922)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.sendMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:308)
at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:289)
at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:249)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:192)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1764)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong...

Comment: i think that you didn't defint your smtp server correctly. Do you have one ? What's his IP ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a local SMTP server or define a different (external) SMTP in the email-ext settings.

Comment: I have already tried that...i have setup the email server in jenkins configuration..but when i tried test configuration,it gave an error

Comment: do you have a SMTP server running on the same machine as jenkins on port 25? Because response 421 means " Service not available, closing transmission channel"

Comment: No..i have now set up smtp server on jenkins...and the error has changed to:   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: well so the initial problem was that you configured a local SMTP that doesn´t exist. Now you have SSL certificate problem and thats a different problem but should be easy to solve when consulting your favorite search engine. Which means my answer solved your initial problem - so maybe you can accept it ;)

Comment: i have accepted the answer..but what about my new problem?